# Ler arquivo e ordernar palavras por ordem alfabética (com remoção de caractéres especiais)

Tags: c, algoritmo

Estou a um tempo tentando achar o erro, mas não estou conseguindo.

O programa consiste em ler um arquivo .txt com o conteúdo abaixo, por exemplo:

> casa-laranja,otorrinolaringologista flor
>   mesa notebook-amora

Em seguida o programa deve retirar os caracteres especiais e as palavras que tenham mais que 20 letras.
E em seguida ordena-las em ordem alfabética, dando a seguinte saída:

> amora casa flor laranja mesa notebook

Já fiz várias coisas e não consigo obter essa saída, gostaria de saber se alguém poderia ajudar e me informar onde estou errando.
Segue o código abaixo e desde já agradeço. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  FILE *arq;
  char ch[50];
  char simbolos[] = {' ', ',', '-','\n'};
  char *palavra = NULL;
  char **matriz;
  int resul, tamanho, i, j, k, matlen;

  //abrindo o arquivo
  arq = fopen("texto.txt", "r");
  //linha
  matriz=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*1024);

  while( (fgets(ch, 1024, arq))!=NULL ){
    palavra = strtok(ch, simbolos);
    tamanho = strlen(palavra);
    if(tamanho > 20){
      //printf("String nao salva\n");
      *palavra = NULL;
    }
    else{
      //coluna
      matriz[i]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*21);
      //copia a string que está no ponteiro teste pra posição I da matriz e imprime na tela, incrementa o i para correr a matriz
      //matlen - conta o tamanho da matriz - insere um elemento, aumenta mais 1 no contador
      strcpy(matriz[i], palavra);
      printf("%s", matriz[i]);
      i++;
      matlen++;
    }
  }

//matlen = variável para armazenar o tamanho da matriz
//comparo as posicoes j começa sempre 1 posição na frente o i
//-1 quer dizer que a primeira palavra [i] fica na fretne da de [j], então nada acontece
for(i=0;i<matlen; i++){
  for(j=i+1;j<matlen; j++){
      resul = strcmp(matriz[i], matriz[j]);
      if(resul == -1){
}
      //teoricamente o único resultado aqui vai ser 1, porque o 0 que é igual vai ser eliminado pela regra que vou fazer la em cima
      else{
        strcpy(palavra, matriz[i]); // teste é um ponteiro auxiliar pra eu armazenar a string e trocar de posição
        strcpy(matriz[i], matriz[j]); //copio a matriz
        strcpy(matriz[j], palavra);
      }
  }
}

//imprimindo a matriz só pra ver se organizou corretamente
printf("\n\n\n%s", matriz[0]);
printf("\n%s", matriz[1]);
printf("\n%s", matriz[2]);
printf("\n%s", matriz[3]);
printf("\n%s", matriz[4]);

fclose(arq);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja que `ch` é declarado com tamanho 50, mas em `fgets` você admite até o tamanho 1024 para colocar em `ch`.

Outra parte estranha é:

```
tamanho = strlen(palavra);
if(tamanho > 20){
  //printf("String nao salva\n");
  *palavra = NULL;
}
```

Dessa forma você só consegue pergar a primeira palavra dos 1024 caracteres obtidos no `fgets`. Tente fazer outro loop interno e uma variável matriz de char, tipo `char palavras[1024][]`, para armazenar todas as palavras; como: `palavras[i] = palavra`.

Veja o exemplo do seguinte endereço: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok